# Mount cifs with Write access for group

Tags: permissions, mount, cifs

I am trying to mount a cifs on RedHat 6.10 with below in `/etc/fstab`:

```
//chq-qaedinas.chq.ei/DataHistory /DataHistory cifs auto,credentials=/etc/samba/user,noexec,umask=0002,uid=20588,gid=50011 0 0
```

But, the file system is mounting it with `drwxr-xr-x`.

How to get the write option for the group?

Does that have to be checked on the Windows Server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try mounting the share with addtional options `file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0775`